# Behaviour of undefined and null keys in ecmascript 5 or 6

Tags: javascript, properties, null, undefined, accessor

I'm interested in knowing what is the correct behaviour when object is accessed by undefined or null key in javascript.

I checked its behaviour in Chrome 46, Firefox 42 and node 0.12.0 and it's the same:

```
var obj = {};
obj[undefined] = 'foo';
obj[undefined]; // 'foo'
obj['undefined']; // 'foo'
obj; // {undefined: 'foo'}
```

or:

```
var obj = {};
obj[null] = 'foo';
obj[null]; // 'foo'
obj['null']; // 'foo'
obj; // {null: 'foo'}
```

Then, it seems that `undefined` and `null` are coerced to strings `'undefined'` and `'null'`. However if I read [ecmascript specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and I see that `RequireObjectCoercible` is used. Reading [RequireObjectCoercible specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-requireobjectcoercible), I see that when it is passed undefined or null as argument, it throws a TypeError exception.

Therefore I don't understand why I reproduce another behaviour when I check it.

---

Edit:

Thanks for Andreas and Bergi

I understand that the behaviour is this because:

> 12.3.2.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> [...]
>
> 9. Let propertyKey be ToPropertyKey(propertyNameValue).
>
> ---
>
> 7.1.14 ToPropertyKey ( argument )
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Return ToString(key).
>
> ---
>
> 7.1.12 ToString ( argument )
>
> The abstract operation ToString converts argument to a value of type String according to Table 12:
>
> [...]
>
> Undefined | Return "undefined".
>
> Null | Return "null".

Right?

Comment: In `obj[undefined], obj['undefined'], obj[null]` the part in `[ ]` equals the `[ Expression ]` part in `MemberExpression [ Expression ]`. Therefor you have to have a look at `4., 5., 6., 9.` and `10.`

Answer (score 1):

`RequireObjectCoercible` is called on the base value, not on the property, before the property reference is constructed. And `obj` is coercible to an object :-) It does throw when you are doing stuff like `undefined.x` or `null[y]`.

Comment: One moment! When is the `RequireObjectCoercible` function called with an argument when `ToObject` is called? How it's works if I calling it so: `RequireObjectCoercible(7)`?